# Discussion on my closed question

Tags: support

[Related question in Meta Earth Science](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/are-questions-about-paleoantropology-suited-for-esse)

---

I am new in the site where I had posted only [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112904/is-it-possible-to-proccess-human-genome-in-a-local-computer) about DNA and computers.

I reopened an account to post [my second question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113529/is-there-evidence-of-an-evolutionary-strategy-similar-to-human-autism-in-mammals) in the site about Pleistocene mamals.

It was closed as "needs more focus".

User @David told me in Main Meta in a deleted post you don't want questions as covid related ones, as we in Earth Sciences we decided to ban id-my-rock questions.

I corrected a bit the question this morning at work (I do nothing in the administration), but wondering if I shouldn't put any more effort on this, so asking to you as it is your site if I can or not do something to reopen or repost my question more clearly to be accepted by your community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I said on the main Meta was *not* that we did not want questions on Covid (I have just left a comment suggesting improvements on one) but that we don’t want people to use the site for discussion, in this case comments on people’s theories. I used Covid as an example because during the pandemic we received post from people floating ideas about how to eradicate the virus or describing how they would create a vaccine.

My justification for this view is, first, what is written on the Biology [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

- “Biology Stack Exchange is a **question and answer** site”
- “This site is all about getting answers. It's **not a discussion forum**.”

and then it gives examples of what type of questions are suitable:

- general questions about biological concepts
- questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions
- questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Questions, questions, questions. And “I have this theory… am I right?” doe not cut it.

The Help page on [the type of questions not to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) amplifies this. The closest example to floating theories is:

> …just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

The word *rant* is not applicable here (I wish they would modify it) but the point that “…am I right?” does not make something a genuine question is relevant.

Let me give an example for Covid§. *In my opinion:*†

A post of the type “How does the covid virus enter cells?” would be an acceptable question (if the answer were not so easy to find) — it addresses a biological problem and has an answer.

A post of the type “Would chemical X prevent covid entering cells and thus be useful as an antiviral?” is not acceptable in my opinion because one can only speculate on an answer. It is possible to make an argument for “no” but there can be no objective “yes”.

A post of the type “I have this idea for a covid antiviral… Do you think it would work?”. Is not an acceptable question. The poster is just floating a theory for discussion. “And this is not a discussion forum.”

---

§ I would mention. (1) the existence of SE Medical Sciences. Questions about disease mechanisms that are more physiological or epidemiological than molecular might be better there — but check their guidelines before posting. (2) “Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology.” So questions relating to one’s personal experience of Covid (or that of one’s acquaintances) should be avoided.

† I am not a moderator. Just a list member who has read the instructions and tries to explain them to new users.